# how to generate compile files for .py in linux

Tags: python, linux

I never used linux till now, I am trying to generate compile files of .py file in Linux. I was able to generate .pyd file in windows. I have used reference from below site

https://pypi.org/project/easycython/
https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html

Able to generate .pyd file in windows using below two command

```
easycython *.py
cythonize -a -i *.py
```

But in linux I am getting error as below

```
bash: easycython: command not found
bash: cythonize: command not found
```

Can anyone please help me with this. Any approach which can compile .py file in linux. Please give me some advice.

Comment: What do you mean by "compile files"?

Comment: Before using Linux easily, you need to accept the fact that you should spend weeks in learning it and reading documentation and books about it. Don't expect to become productive in Linux with a day of work, you will need more. Read also http://linuxhowtos.org/ and spend days in reading https://man7.org/ and https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/

Answer (score 2):

You can install `cython` with `pip install cython` and `easycython` with `pip install easycython`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help , able to see .so file in linux post installing easycython. Thank a lot. :)